# Let $G$ be a nonabelian group of order $p^{3},$ where $p$ is a prime. Show that $G$ has exactly $p^{2}+p-1$ distinct conjugacy classes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups

**Problem**

> Let $G$ be a nonabelian group of order $p^{3},$ where $p$ is a prime.  Show that $G$ has exactly $p^{2}+p-1$ distinct conjugacy classes.

**Attempt**

> Let $G$ be a nonabelian group with $|G|=p^{3},$ where $p$ is a prime. Recall $|Z(G)|=p$ from the previous problem (1)[I've prove already]. By Class equation, 
>   \begin{equation} \label{5 - 1}
> p^{3}=|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum_{i=1}^{n}[G:C(a_i)]=p+\sum_{i=1}^{n}[G:C(a_i)],
> \end{equation}
>   where ${\rm class~}a_1$, ${\rm class~}a_2$, $\cdots$, ${\rm class~}a_n$ are the nonsingleton conjugacy classes in $G$. It is enough to show that $n=p^2-1$.
>
> Since $2 \leq\left[G: C\left(a_{i}\right)\right]=\frac{|G|}{|C(a_i)|}=\frac{p^3}{|C(a_i)|},$ we have 
>   $$
> | C\left(a_{i}\right)|=1{\rm ~or~}p{\rm ~or~}p^2{\rm ~or~p^3}
> $$
>   for each $i=1,2,\cdots, n$. Note that $| C\left(a_{i}\right)|\neq 1$ for all $i$ since $G$ is nonabelian and $| C\left(a_{i}\right)|\neq p^3$ for all $i$ because $|Z(G)|=p$. Assume that there is $j \in N$ such that $|C\left(a_{j}\right)|=p$. Then 
>   $$
> \left| \frac{G}{C(a_j)}\right|=\frac{|G|}{|C(a_j)|}=\frac{p^3}{p}=p^2.
> $$
>   Hence, $G/C(a_j)$ is abelian. Then -----??------, which is a contradiction. Hence, $|C\left(a_{i}\right)|=p^2$ for all $i$. 
>   ---------skip--------------

**Question**

1. Am I approaching in the right way?
2. If good, how to prove the '-----??------'.

Comment: I think $|C(a_i)| \neq 1$ because $Z(G) \subset C(a_i)$. And $|C(a_i)| \neq p^3$ because then $a_i \in Z(G)$ but you've already counted them. Finally, $|C(a_j)| = p$ implies that $Z(G) = C(a_j)$ because clearly $Z(G) \subset C(a_j)$ and they have the same cardinality. If $Z(G) = C(a_j)$ then $a_j$ is in $Z(G)$, which again you've already counted.

Comment: Thanks Wang. But I wonder why $Z(G) \subset C(a_{j})$. Is it just definition?

Comment: $C(a_j)$ is defined as the centralizer of $a_j$, i.e. the elements $g \in G$ such that $g a_j g^{-1} = a_j$. Obviously this holds for all elements in the centralizer $Z(G)$ of $G$ because these elements commute with all elements in $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $\mathcal Z(G)\subset\mathcal C(a_i)\neq G$ we must have $p$ $|$ $|\mathcal C(a_i)|$ $|$ $p^3$. Therefore $|\mathcal C(a_i)|=p^2$. $$\therefore p^3=p+np$$ $$\therefore n=p^2-1$$

Comment: Thanks Oliver.  But I wonder why $Z(G) \subset C(a_{j})$. Is it just definition?

Comment: @himath. Yes. By definition, the "centralizer" $\mathcal C(a_i)$ of $a_i$ is the $G$ subgroup made of those elements which commute with $a_i$. Since the members of $\mathcal Z(G)$ commute with all group members we must then have $\mathcal Z(G)\subseteq\mathcal C(a_i)$. But since $a_i\in\mathcal C(a_i)$ itself is not a member of $\mathcal Z(G)$ then $\mathcal Z(G)$ itself is a proper subgroup of $\mathcal C(a_i)$ while $\mathcal C(a_i)$ is a proper subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$You might try this argument. If $a \in G \setminus Z(G)$, then $C_{G}(a) < G$, so $C_{G}(a)$ has order less than $p^{3}$. Now $\Span{Z(G), a}$ has order at least $p^{2}$, as $a \notin Z(G)$, and $\Span{Z(G), a} \le C_{G}(a)$.

Answer (score 3):

The conjugacy classes are the orbits of the action of $G$ on itself by conjugation. Then, by the Burnside Lemma we have:

\begin{alignat}{1}
|\mathcal{O}| &= \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}|\operatorname{Stab}(g)| \\
&= \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}|C_G(g)| \\
&= \frac{1}{|G|}\Bigl(\sum_{g\in Z(G)}|C_G(g)|+\sum_{g\in G\setminus Z(G)}|C_G(g)|\Bigr) \\
\tag 1
\end{alignat}

Now, $g \in Z(G) \Rightarrow C_G(g)=G \Rightarrow |C_G(g)|=|G|$, while $g \in G\setminus Z(G) \Rightarrow |C_G(g)|<|G|$; but, for nonabelian groups, $Z(G)$ is a *proper* subgroup of *all* the centralizers, which then for noncentral elements must all have order $p^2$. Therefore $(1)$ reads:

\begin{alignat}{1}
|\mathcal{O}| &= \frac{1}{p^3}\Bigl(p p^3+(p^3-p)p^2\Bigr) \\
&= p+p^2-1
\tag 2
\end{alignat}